# How do I determine which python modules to pip-install for these imports?

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, pip

I'm trying to run some scripts, with some subscripts, and each of these performs some import's. These are, overall (and dropping those with the `from` argument beginning with a dot):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import abc
import argparse
import copy
import csv
import json
import os
import re
import time
import xlsxwriter
import yaml
```

I want to try and use pip to install the modules I need for these imports to work, using pip. That is, I want to run:

```
python3 -m pip install foo bar baz whatever
```

and have all the necessities for running my models. This is not entirely trivial, since, for instance, if I

```
python3 -m pip search yaml
```

there are lots of modules, but none named just plain `yaml`. There's a `yaml-1.3`, but I'm not 100% sure that's the one I need; while `xlsxwriter` does exist as such.

So, my question is: How do I determine which module names I need to install, for the above imports?

Comment: The majority of these modules are in the standard library and do not need to be installed prior to use. If in doubt, try the import in the python console to see if you already have it available. Then edit the question to make it more specific to the modules you are still unable to install.

Comment: @Mark: That solves part of my problem, i.e. lets me filter out what's already installed. But for those modules which _aren't_ installed - it doesn't help. It says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'` for example, but there is no pip module named just `yaml` (and `yaml-1.3` is not what I need).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be some automated way to achieve this fully. However, here's the best I managed to do:

1. As @Mark suggests:

   1.1 Start a Python REPL (i.e. run `python3` at the command line)

   1.2 paste all of those `import` commands

   1.3 check which modules Python lists as missing; everything else is already covered, 
   either by the "standard library" or by modules already-installed on your system.
2. Try installing the missing modules as named by Python itself. You don't have to use `python3 -m pip install`; you could use `pip3  install` (on most systems).
3. For those modules that pip fails to locate, search the web: DuckDuckGO, StackOverflow etc. for "python foo module" or "how do I install the foo module for Python" etc.
4. If all else fails, check your operating system distribution for Python-module-related packages with the modules you're missing. Some modules are usually obtained that way.

In my case, `yaml` comes from `pyyaml` - as explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python); and I installed it using pip. `tkinter` - doesn't seem to be available through pip, but I found it as a distribution package (in my case - Cygwin), and installed it.